# In Microsoft SQL How do I return only 1 row per ID with multiple column results

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I need to have one row per driver id that has columns that are calculated. Currently the GROUP BY is requiring "JobEndComments" which is creating multiple rows, instead of one.

I am getting:

```
HOT_DriverID,Driver Name,Successfully Completed,No Post,No Access,Not Allowed,Not Found,Not Tall Enough,No Permission
3   William Arboleda    768 0   0   0   0   0   0<br>
3   William Arboleda    0   0   1   0   0   0   0<br>
4   Fredy Garcia    912 0   0   0   0   0   0<br>
4   Fredy Garcia    0   0   0   0   2   0   0<br>
7   Mario Estrada   497 0   0   0   0   0   0<br>
7   Mario Estrada   0   1   0   0   0   0   0<br>
7   Mario Estrada   0   0   1   0   0   0   0<br>
```

When I want:

```
HOT_DriverID,Driver Name,Successfully Completed,No Post,No Access,Not Allowed,Not Found,Not Tall Enough,No Permission
3   William Arboleda    768 0   1   0   0   0   0<br>
4   Fredy Garcia    912 0   0   0   2   0   0<br>
7   Mario Estrada   497 1   1   0   0   0   0<br>
```

I have tried eliminating the GROUP BY on JobEndComments but this generates errors.

```
SELECT HOT_DriverID, d.First_Name + ' ' + d.Last_Name AS 'Driver Name', 
ISNULL((SELECT COUNT(JobEndComments) WHERE JobEndComments = '000' AND HOT_DriverID = HOT_DriverID),0) AS 'Successfully Completed',
ISNULL((SELECT COUNT(JobEndComments) WHERE JobEndComments = '111' AND HOT_DriverID = HOT_DriverID),0) AS 'No Post',
ISNULL((SELECT COUNT(JobEndComments) WHERE JobEndComments = '222' AND HOT_DriverID = HOT_DriverID),0) AS 'No Access',
ISNULL((SELECT COUNT(JobEndComments) WHERE JobEndComments = '333' AND HOT_DriverID = HOT_DriverID),0) AS 'Not Allowed',
ISNULL((SELECT COUNT(JobEndComments) WHERE JobEndComments = '444' AND HOT_DriverID = HOT_DriverID),0) AS 'Not Found',
ISNULL((SELECT COUNT(JobEndComments) WHERE JobEndComments = '555' AND HOT_DriverID = HOT_DriverID),0) AS 'Not Tall Enough',
ISNULL((SELECT COUNT(JobEndComments) WHERE JobEndComments = '777' AND HOT_DriverID = HOT_DriverID),0) AS 'No Permission'
FROM tbl_Jobs_IFC j
JOIN Drivers d ON d.Code = j.HOT_DriverID
WHERE ConfirmedDate IS NOT NULL
AND HOT_DriverID > 0
AND (HOT_Date >= @From AND HOT_Date < @To)
AND d.First_Name NOT LIKE 'Pend%'
AND d.First_Name NOT LIKE '%E-D%'
AND d.Active > 0
AND d.Printable > 0
--GROUP BY JobEndComments, c.description, c.JobEndComment, Hot_DriverID, d.First_Name, d.Last_Name
--GROUP BY Hot_DriverID, d.First_Name, d.Last_Name, JobEndComment, JobEndComments
GROUP BY Hot_DriverID, d.First_Name, d.Last_Name, JobEndComments
ORDER BY HOT_DriverID, JobEndComments
```

I really only want one result per driver id. I can work around it via code and deciphering the multiple rows, but I am fairly certain this can be accomplished in SQL. If I leave out JobEndComments in the GROUP BY I get an error:

> 'tbl_Jobs_IFC.JobEndComments' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is so weird.  You are using subqueries with no `FROM` clause.

Just use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT HOT_DriverID, d.First_Name + ' ' + d.Last_Name AS "Driver Name", 
       SUM(CASE WHEN JobEndComments = '000' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "Successfully Completed",
       SUM(CASE WHEN JobEndComments = '111' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "No Post",
       . . .
FROM tbl_Jobs_IFC j JOIN
     Drivers d 
     ON d.Code = j.HOT_DriverID
WHERE ConfirmedDate IS NOT NULL AND
      HOT_DriverID > 0 AND
      (HOT_Date >= @From AND HOT_Date < @To) AND
      d.First_Name NOT LIKE 'Pend%'
      d.First_Name NOT LIKE '%E-D%' AND
      d.Active > 0 AND
      d.Printable > 0
GROUP BY Hot_DriverID, d.First_Name, d.Last_Name
ORDER BY HOT_DriverID;
```

Note that I also changed the escape character for the column aliases.  Only use single quotes for date and string constants.

Comment: Thank you Gordon! That did the trick. I didn't know that I shouldn't use single quotes in column aliases. Thank you again. PS, what was the weird part?

Comment: Gordon Linoff, What would be the reasoning for adding another FROM condition when I am using data FROM the entire query and the parameters of the FROM, WHERE, GROUP BY & ORDER already established? I could see if the criteria was different but as the same, why? Just curious.

Comment: @MichaelWood . . . I don't understand the question.  I have not added any new conditions to the query (at least not intentionally).

Comment: You posted "This is so weird. You are using subqueries with no FROM clause." I was just asking why would you want to add another FROM clause in the subqueries when the larger scope of the query creates the correct selection set in which to draw data from?